# ValueError when finding elements in a list that satisfy condition - list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, list-comprehension, valueerror

```
def dist(px,py,qx,qy,bx,by):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power((px - qx)-(bx*np.floor( ((px-qx)/bx) + 0.5)),2.0)))

dist_vals = [[dist(x1,y1,x2,y2,10,10) for x2,y2 in zip(xpos2,ypos2)] for x1,y1 in zip(xpos1,ypos1)]
counts=[sum(x>r and x<=r+drval for x in dist_vals) for r in rvals]
```

I'm using the code above in Python 3.6.9 to find all elements in a list (dist_vals) that fall within a shell of radius r and thickness drval, for all r in rvals. xpos1,ypos1,xpos2 and ypos2 are arrays of created as follows:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
xpos1 = rng.choice(1000, size=50, replace=False)/100
ypos1 = rng.choice(1000, size=50, replace=False)/100
xpos2 = rng.choice(1000, size=50, replace=False)/100
ypos2 = rng.choice(1000, size=50, replace=False)/100
```

I tried to use list comprehension to reduce the run time. I get the following error message when I run this:

"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

If I do the following, I get no error messages:

```
a = [i for i in range(10)]
b = [sum(x>r and x<=r+3 for x in a) for r in a]
```

Output: b = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0], exactly as expected. I do not understand the difference between the two cases and why the ValueError is raised. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: the ambiguity error is asked about frequently!

Comment: I see that and I went through everything I could find. But the trouble for me is that I am checking if the condition is satisfied elementwise, so a.any() or a.all() do not work in my case. The simplistic example I tried works without raising any errors, so I don't understand what is going wrong in my actual code.

Comment: `and` only works for scalar values, not arrays

Comment: `(x>r) & (x<=r+drval)` is the correct of doing array tests

Comment: This worked. Do not see the error message anymore. The two lines below got me what I wanted: 
`counts_a=[sum((x>r) & (x<=r+drval) for x in dist_vals) for r in rvals]`
`counts=[np.sum(counts_a[i]) for i in range(50)]`
thank you @hpaulj and @Ethan Seal